# What is the role of .s files in a C project?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am working with an ARM Cortex M3 chip (STM32F2) and ST provides a "standard peripheral library". It has some useful .c and .h files. It also has .s files.

What is the purpose of these .s files in the context of a C project? How do I get my compiler/linker/? to take them into account?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The .s extension is the convention used by GNU and many other tool-chains for assembler files.

Last I looked the STM32 Standard Peripheral Library itself contains no assembler files, however the CMSIS library contains start-up code for various STM32 parts, for example startup_stm32f2xx.s is start-up code for all STM32F2xx series devices.  There are different implementations for different tool-chains; you need to build and link the file associated with your specific part and tool-chain.  If you are using an example project that builds and runs or an IDE that creates part-specific projects for you, this will probably already have been done - if you have code that runs it certainly has.

How you build and link the code will depend on what tool-chain you are using.  Most IDE based tools will automatically recognise the extension and invoke the assembler to generate an object file that will be linked like any other.  The exact content differs slightly between tool-chain versions, but primarily creates the C runtime environment (stack and heap), initialises the processor, defines an initial interrupt/exception vector table, initialises static data and jumps to main().

The core of the file for the Keil/ARM RealView version for example looks like this:

```
; Reset handler
Reset_Handler    PROC
                 EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK]
        IMPORT  SystemInit
        IMPORT  __main
                 LDR     R0, =SystemInit
                 BLX     R0
                 LDR     R0, =__main
                 BX      R0
                 ENDP
```

`Reset_Handler` is the address Program Counter (PC) register will be set to after a processor reset.

`SystemInit` is an external C code function that does the bulk of the initialisation - this may need customisation for your hardware.  Cortex-M is unusual in that it can start running C code immediately after reset because the vector table includes both the reset address and the initial stack pointer address, which is automatically loaded to the SP register on reset.  As a result you do not need much assembler knowledge to get one running.

`__main()` is the compiler supplied entry point for your C code.  It is not the main() function you write, but performs initialisation for the standard library, static data, the heap before calling your `main()' function.

The GCC version is somewhat more involved since it does much of the work done by `__main()` in the Keil/ARM RealView version, but essentially it performs the same function.

Note that in the CMSIS `SystemInit()` is defined in system_stm32f2xx.c, and may need customisation for your board (correct crystal frequency, PLL setup, external SRAM configuration etc.).  Because this is C code, and well commented, you will probably be more comfortable with it.

Comment: Except I just noticed you specified STM32F2xx.  The answer still applies, except the respective file names are startup_stm32f2xx.s and system_stm32f2xx.c in your case.  I've modified the answer to make it more specific to the STM32F2.

Comment: Clifford - in the documentation on ARM's website it mentions that the other routine in startup_xxx.s, __user_initial_stack_heap, should not use more than 88 bytes of stack. Do you know where that limitation is coming from? See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0099a/armlib_cihhdahf.htm

Comment: @NickHalden : Do you think perhaps that deserves being posted as a question on its own?  This question is over two years old, and not even your question. This is not what he comments section is for - SO is not a discussion forum. Besides; you'll get a bigger audience that way.

Comment: @Clifford Well you were explaining the exact file that I referenced so I didn't think it was too much of a stretch, but I'll admit I did not notice how old this was. I posed a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643465/arm-cortex-m3-startup-code. Please answer there if possible, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

They usually contain assembly code. The assembler turns them into object files which are later linked by the linker with the main stuff. But I imagine it does depend on the compiler, toolchain etc.

Answer (score 3):

The .s files usually contain the Vector tables. It defines what should the system do when an interrupt occurs. This table (code) is placed in a memory address defined by you in linker file. For example, every time a reset occurs what or rather where should your processor begin from , what code should it run. similarly, there are other handlers ( interrupt vectors). In STM32 , usually the controller loops on particular handlers.
As given in the below example:[See this link for detailed explanation](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/simplest-bare-metal-program-for-arm/)

```
    .section INTERRUPT_VECTOR, "x"
    .global _Reset
    _Reset:
      B Reset_Handler /* Reset */
      B . /* Undefined */
      B . /* SWI */
      B . /* Prefetch Abort */
      B . /* Data Abort */
      B . /* reserved */
      B . /* IRQ */
      B . /* FIQ */

    Reset_Handler:
      LDR sp, =stack_top
      BL c_entry
      B .
```

This assembly code later is converted to object files and linked with your .c files and .ld to create a .elf or .bin files.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got a Keil-based development environment for your ST kit.  Depending on the version of your compiler, the project file should have different sections for C, C++, and assembler code.  In your IDE, open your project and look for "Project Properties" or something like it.

You can import and export symbols to and from the assembler code so that it and the C/C++ code will link.  With Keil it all integrates reasonably well.

The EXPORT directive tells the assembler to make the specified symbol public so that your C/C++ code can link to it.

The IMPORT directive tells the assembler that the specified symbol is defined elsewhere and will be resolved at link time.