# ARM Cortex-M3 Startup Code

Tags: arm, embedded, cpu-architecture, cortex-m

I'm trying to understand how the initialization code works that ships with Keil (realview v4) for the STM32 microcontrollers. Specifically, I'm trying to understand how the stack is initialized.

In the [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0099a/armlib_cihhdahf.htm) on ARM's website it mentions that one of the routines in startup_xxx.s, [`__user_initial_stack_heap`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0099a/armlib_cihhdahf.htm), should not use more than 88 bytes of stack. Do you know where that limitation is coming from?

It seems that when the reset handler calls System_Init it is executing a couple functions in a C environment which I believe means it is using some form of a temporary stack (it allocates a few automatic variables). However, all of those stack'd items should be out of scope once it returns back and then calls `__main` which is where `__user_initial_stack_heap` is called from.

So why is there this requirement for `__user_initial_stack_heap` to not use more than 88 bytes? Does the rest of `__main` use a ton of stack or something?

Any explanation of the cortex-m3 stack architecture as it relates to the startup sequence would be fantastic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will see from the [__user_initial_stackheap()](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0099a/armlib_cihhdahf.htm) documentation, that the function is for *legacy support* and that it is superseded by [__user_setup_stackheap()](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0099a/armlib_cjagaaha.htm); the documentation for the latter provides a clue ragarding your question:

> Unlike __user_initial_stackheap(), __user_setup_stackheap() works with ***systems where the application starts with a value of sp (r13) that is already correct***, for example, Cortex-M3
>
> [..]
>
> Using __user_setup_stackheap() rather than __user_initial_stackheap() improves code size because there is no requirement for a ***temporary stack***.

On Cortex-M the sp is initialised on reset by the hardware from a value stored in the vector table, on older ARM7 and ARM9 devices this is not the case and it is necessary to set the stack-pointer in software.  The start-up code needs a small stack for use before the user defined stack is applied - this may be the case for example if the user stack were in external memory and could not be used until the memory controller were initialised.  The 88 byte restriction is imposed simply because this *temporary stack* is sized to be as small as possible since it is probably unused after start-up.

In your case in STM32 (a Cortex-M device), it is likely that there is in fact no such restriction, but you should perhaps update your start-up code to use the newer function to be certain.  That said, given the required behaviour of this function and the fact that its results are returned in registers, I would suggest that 88 bytes would be rather extravagant if you were to need that much!  Moreover, you only need to reimplement it if you are using scatter loading file as described.

Comment: My lack of understanding centers around this temporary stack. As I mentioned, System_Init() is called before __user_initial_stackheap() and so it must be using some stack before that even comes into play right? If that's the case, how did the legacy function work on ARM7 and ARM9... it must've just put the temporary stack wherever the boot up default was for SP? On cortex-m3 my user stack will overlap with said temporary stack, is it ok to place values in the user stack during the execution of __user_initial_stackheap() or is the temp stack still in use and that would corrupt it?

Comment: @NickHalden :  I'd have to wade through the code to figure all that out, but you could do that! On ARM7, the sp would I presume have been set very early after reset (in ARM7 there is not true vector table, it is a block of JMP instructions); it would be the address of a statically allocated block.  On Cortex-M3, there probably is no temporary stack, and the current value of sp is returned.  I am really wondering what you think __user_initial_stackheap() needs to do that needs this.

Comment: something like this: http://www.keil.com/forum/21045/stack-initialization-with-constant/

Comment: @NickHalden : You seem to be asking an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. If filling the stack is what you want to do, ask a question about that directly.  The purpose of this function is merely to return the memory model parameters, not to do any actual *initialisation*.  I suggest that you iterate from the bottom of the stack region up-to the current sp in order to avoid corrupting stack already in use.

Comment: Well I would rather learn the background information and then develop my own strategy for achieving my goal rather than simply ask how to do the specific task. Teach a man to fish or something. In any case thanks for the advice.

Comment: @NickHalden : Fair enough, but you may get questions marked down as "too broad" in that case.  Also you have to ask questions in the question - not the comments. Comments  are temporary and not searchable, so are of less use a a community resource.  If I get a change to look at the code I may elaborate this answer.

Comment: Which code are you referring to exactly? As far as i can tell we don't have access to __main...

Comment: @NickHalden : Sorry, just realised I left you hanging there! You can run the code in a debugger and step into __main at the assembly level, but I don't actually recall what I was going to look at.