# Conflicting function declaration and macro?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am looking at this header file in linux kernel:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/boot/string.h

```
#ifndef BOOT_STRING_H
#define BOOT_STRING_H

/* Undef any of these macros coming from string_32.h. */
#undef memcpy
#undef memset
#undef memcmp

void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len);
void *memset(void *dst, int c, size_t len);
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t len);

#define memcpy(d,s,l) __builtin_memcpy(d,s,l)
#define memset(d,c,l) __builtin_memset(d,c,l)
#define memcmp  __builtin_memcmp

...

#endif /* BOOT_STRING_H */
```

I can't figure out what does the #undef + function declaration + macro define on memcpy, memset and memcmp do. For example, it first declares a function memcpy and then defines a macro memcpy after that. I am not sure what's the purpose of this. I find that this function is defined here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/boot/copy.S#L20. If somewhere in the code uses memcpy (for example here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/boot/main.c#L40) uses memcpy what does it use? The function defined in copy.S or the __builtin_memcpy?

Comment: Possibly the purpose of the declarations is so that it still works if people bypass the following macroes (e.g. undef them)

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration and macro are not conflicting.  `memcpy()` has several definitions in the kernel, which is hinted at by the comment above the `#undef` blocks -- there is another `memcpy()` defined in [string_32.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/string_32.h#L171).

`#undef memcpy` is cancelling out the `#define` found in *string_32.h* so that it will not exist in any file that includes */boot/string.h*.  `memcpy()` is then declared, and a new macro is built for it.

The `#define` statement is creating a new macro for `memcpy()`, as the one from *string_32.h* no longer exists in this context.  Kernel developers use macros for a variety of reasons; see answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653839/what-are-c-macros-useful-for) for more.

*/boot/copy.S* is an [assembly file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285410/what-are-s-files/10285461).  You can read a bit about its role [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9821279/4249424).  The `memcpy()` being used in */boot/main.c* is coming from */boot/string.h* -- check the include statements.

Comment: when you say it is coming from /boot/string.h do you mean the __builtin_memcpy? My assumption is that it eventually use the one in copy.S otherwise why there is such a definition in the same module.

Comment: `__builtin_memcpy(d,s,l)` is a macro for `memcpy(d,s,l)`, meaning they evaluate to the same thing: the definition of `void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len);`.  Since you don't actually see `__builtin_memcpy()` being called on the line in **/boot/main.c** that you linked to, you can safely assume that you're calling `memcpy()` directly. The version of `memcpy` in **copy.S** is being used by an assembler, not in **/boot/main.c**, which is discussed in one of the posts I linked to.